# is there a place where new phones release dates are posted?

Tags: manufacturers

I recently got a new Inspire 4G and its awesome but how can I know if something new is coming out in a few days and I should have waited? Is there a site that keeps track of this stuff? Sorry if this is not the correct place to ask this. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually didn't know this until just a few minutes ago but you can use [pdadb.net's pda-chooser](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdachooser) to search by release year (so not exact date but at least its something).  Obviously if its not in the database it won't appear and I'm guessing that only confirmed devices/dates are entered.  That along with Gus's answer should help.  You may also want to check out [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/)

Answer (score 3):

I typically find out about new android devices coming out on [gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/t/android). The only official place I know of is Google's [phone store](http://www.google.com/phone/#). It doesn't list new phones that are coming out, only what is currently out.

Comment: thanks - i tried voting up your answer but it wouldn't let me. I'll check gizmodo out.

Answer (score 2):

Daniels suggestion (pdadb.net) definitely has the most comprehensive list but I'm not thrilled with the UI. It's not the most user friendly.

I prefer PhoneScoops search which seems to cover all the major US devices.  **Here is a link to a search for results of all the ["Coming Soon" Android phones](http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/finder_results.php?m=s&w=s&avr=r&av_1=y&plr=r&pl_6=y).**

Also, if you are looking for Blogs, [BGR.com](http://www.bgr.com/tag/android/) is always seems to be one of the first to report on new devices.

Answer (score 0):

[GSMArena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/news.php3) is another popular site for cellphone news and device information.  As with PDAnet mentioned by Daniel, you can search by "coming soon" devices that meet whatever specifications you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidauthority.com and http://www.gsmarena.com are the best sites for new stuff and mobiles !